# Detecting OS platform in Sikuli (jython)

Tags: python, jython, platform, sikuli

I have a problem with getting os platform name under sikuli (using jython).

When I use `os.uname()[0]` or `platform.system()` the return value is `'Java'`.

I would be very grateful if someone would give a workaround.

Edit: 
Sikuli function Env.getOS() also isn't a solution - return 'MAC' under my Ubuntu -.-.

Comment: See [get environment ( windows or unix) using jython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014776/get-environment-windows-or-unix-using-jython).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try `platform.platform()`:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'Java-1.7.0_07-Java_HotSpot-TM-_64-Bit_Server_VM,_23.3-b01,_Oracle_Corporation-on-Mac_OS_X-10.7.5-x86_64'
```

There you'll find more useful methods:
http://www.jython.org/docs/library/platform.html